# A quick question on monotone functions and supremum of pre-images

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a (not necessarily strictly) increasing function (so $a\leq b\Rightarrow f(a)\leq f(b))$. If for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that the $\sup f^{-1}(\alpha)=-\infty$, does it then imply that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)>\alpha\}=\mathbb{R}$??

I don't agree it does but read in some notes that this is obviously true.  I don't think it is right as $\sup f^{-1}(\alpha)=-\infty\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(\alpha)=\emptyset$, so then how does this then imply that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)<\alpha\}=\emptyset$, if $f$ is non-decreasing?  I think a simple counter example would be the following:

$f(x)=x$ $\text{for}\space\space x\in(-\infty,1)$; $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[1,3)$; and finally $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[3,\infty)$.

Thus $f^{-1}(2)=\emptyset$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)<2\}=(-\infty,3)$

Also I think, where the notes might of gone wrong is that $\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)>\alpha\} = \sup f^{-1}(\alpha)$ but only when both are non-empty proper subsets or one is empty and the other is the entire space.

So would appreciate if any one can clear this up for me and tell me if I am right or the notes are?  And if I am wrong please tell me why?  Thanks in advance

Comment: $f(x) = \alpha -1$ will be an easier counterexample.

Comment: The assertion as stated is incorrect. Whether or not the note is wrong depends on context (may be there are other more assumptions?)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback but then are the notes right that $\sup f^{−1}(α)=-\infty$, implies that $\{x∈R|f(x)>α\}=\mathbb{R}$ or are they wrong?  No other assumptions needed. Context of notes was to prove increasing functions are Borel measurable.

Comment: Um.....A constant function is increasing (though not strictly increasing), no? Also is $f^{-1}(alpha) = \{x: f(x) = \alpha\}$ your definition?

Comment: My mistake, I read your function as $f(x)=x-1$ and yes your function is much neater.